# PHP save data line by line in array?

Tags: php

I want to save array to the the file.
for this i create the code like this

```
<?PHP
$links = array();

print_r($links);

  file_put_contents("microsoft.csv", $links);

?>
```

code works fine .but it save data as the one strings.
I want to save data line by line like this.

data1

data2

data3

### -

so on

dear sir how do to it??

Comment: Look into [`fputcsv()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**

```
    $data=array();
    array_push($data,"data1");
    array_push($data,"data1");
    $f=fopen("demo.txt","a");
    foreach($data as $a)
    {
        fwrite($f,$a."\r\n");

    }
   fclose($f);
```

hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

use array_push function to add data into array and after put content into csv file using file_put_contents()